# unable to do padding-left - div two lines issue

Tags: css, concrete5

Provided the code link below

http://jsfiddle.net/4uw2o9s3/1/

I want to add a padding of 5px to the left of div #siteTitle content "line1" .  But if i have the padding-left css rule under the div #siteTitle the two inner divs #siteTitle and "#quickNav"  becomes split into two  different lines.  I want the content line1 and line2 in the same line with padding-left of 5px added to the line1 alone.  could any one help me regarding this.  Thanks a lot.

```
   #siteTitle {
        text-align:left;
        padding-left:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vLbLbobf/1/

The problem is you have 2 columns side-by-side, each being 50% wide. When you then apply 5px padding to one of those as well, you get 50% + 50% + 5px width, which forces the second column down beneath the first.

The easiest, quickest fix is to put `text-indent: 5px` on `#siteTitle` instead of `padding-left`. This will only affect the first line of content, but if you only **have** one line, it'll work without any problems.

You can also put a `<div>` inside `#siteTitle`, then apply the following CSS rule

```
#siteTitle > div { padding-left: 5px }
```

This will apply the padding to an element which **isn't** set to 50% width, so it won't affect the parent column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and info.  Will be using text-indent.  If i add the  padding-left under the #siteTitle does css cant interpret that i am adding the css rule inside the 50% width?  Is it a css syntax? css class col 50% is added to the div #siteTitle.

Comment: It's something called the "box model". Basically, it says "the actual width of an element is the total of its border, padding and width", and since your padding pushed the widths over 100%, they dropped onto another line